# Backing up raspberry pi sd card image creates tiny file

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using win32diskimager to backup my sd card and it just creates a 57MB file rather than 16GB of the actual card.I am following all the instructions I have found (ie I open a copy of an image (as diskimager will not create one from scratch) then select my sd card and then click read)

It is obviously just backing up the windows readable partition and not the linux one.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you must do this in Windows? Can't you use something like *dd* in Linux instead?

Comment: The only linux machine I have is the raspberry pi that I am trying to backup the sd card image for. All my other computers are Windows. Plus all the online posts seem to be able to do this with win32diskimager, no one ever mentions that they are having issues with it only seeing the 57MB partition.

Comment: Never used that program myself so no idea if it does or doesn't work. Which version of Windows are you using anyway?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Ok, it looks like it may be an issue with my internal card reader. I have plugged in a external reader and it is now taking an age to backup the card (which looks far more promising), I will post back on here if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with my internal card reader. I plugged in an external one and everything has worked fine.